# command to truncate quoted strings in a file?

Tags: perl, sed, awk

I have a file that contains several lines of:

```
revision="abcdabcdabcd0000111122223333"
revision="0000111122223333444455556666"
```

And I want to truncate the quoted string (e.g., to 8)  like this:

```
revision="abcdabcd"
revision="00001111"
```

How can I use `sed`/`awk`/`perl` to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
sed -i 's/\(revision="........\)[^"]*"/\1"/' file
```

Answer (score 3):

Is the keyword always revision?  Is the information in the string always longer than 8 characters?

I think I'd be looking at something like:

```
sed 's/^\([a-z]*\)="\([^"]\{1,8\}\)[^"]*"/\1="\2"/' input > output
```

This looks for any lower-case only keyword (which is remembered) before an equals sign and a double quote, then finds 1-8 non-double quote characters (which are remembered), followed by zero or more other non-double quotes and a double quote; these are replaced by the keyword, equals, double quote, the remembered non-double quotes, and a double quote.  If there is any trailing material, it is left unmodified.

Comment: (+1)... Typo: It needs the `s` at the start.  `sed 's/...`

Comment: Thanks - to @Peter.O and Glenn.

Answer (score 0):

A perl solution:

```
perl -pi.bak -we 's/^revision="[^\n"]{0,8}\K.*/"/' myfile.txt
```

Will save a backup in `myfile.txt.bak`. Remove `i.bak` to just see output without making changes to the file. Remove `.bak` to not store backup (irreversible).

The regex will find and alter any line that starts with `revision="`. After this match, it will preserve the following 0-8 characters that are not double quote or newline(*), and remove the rest. It will add a double quote to the end of the line, before newline.

(*) Newline added to prevent the edge case of embedded newlines or badly formatted lines corrupting the file. This will "fix" open double quotes by adding a closing one.

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -i~ -pe's/^revision="[^"]{0,8}\K[^"]+//' file
```